# Documentation for new String.Format syntax in VB.NET ( $ before leading quote mark )

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm used to the [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) method in VB.NET:

```
Dim mystring = String.Format("Today is {0:d}", Now)
```

Recently, however, I stumbled upon something like this, which is refreshingly shorter:

```
Dim mystring = $"Today is {Now}"
```

However, I wasn't able to find documentation for this new syntax. I would like to know how to use format masks with it, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called "string interpolation" so you can find information by searching for that term.  That said, format specifiers work the same way as for `String.Format`:

```
Dim mystring = $"Today is {Now:d}"
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I was trying to put the mask between quotemarks.